# How do I change the colors using React-Material UI Theme provider. Version 5

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

There is a question identical to mine, but the answers given didn't work for me (nor the person who asked the question), I'm trying to change the color primary to be grey instead of blue.

According to the [documentation](https://mui.com/material-ui/customization/theming/), something like this should work.

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom/client';
import './index.css';
import App from './App';
import reportWebVitals from './reportWebVitals';
import { ThemeProvider, createTheme } from '@mui/material'



const root = ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById('root'));

const theme = createTheme({
  pallate:{
    primary:{
      main:"#ccc"
    }
  }
});

root.render(
  <React.StrictMode>
    <ThemeProvider theme={theme}>
      <App />
    </ThemeProvider>
  </React.StrictMode>
);

reportWebVitals();
```

This doesn't work, and the colour remains blue.

Comment: You have a typo, it should be "palette" instead of "pallate".

Comment: You're right lol, should I remove my post? I got banned again.

Comment: It's up to you buddy.